# Subir Laravel 7 a hosting con SSH

Tags: laravel, hosting, ssh

Para conectarme a SSH desde Windows ¿necesito instalarme algo? En el hosting me han activado la SSH y tengo mi repo en GitHub, y estaba buscando tutoriales para subirlo al hosting y en algunos pone algo de un programa que se llama PuTTY, pero no se si para subir el proyecto al hosting eso es necesario. Miré en mi máquina y tiene instalado OpenSsh Client y yo he instalado OpenSsh Server (aunque tampoco estoy segura de si lo necesitaba...).
¿Alguien me podría guiar?

Comment: Entra por ssh al server y haces un clone del proyecto en el apache (donde te convenga dentro de `/var/www/html `) luego tendras que configurar cosas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que necesitas es un cliente SSH, no un servidor. Mediante el cliente te conectas al server de tu hosting.
Si estás en Windows Putty es muy recomendado, pero si no me equivoco el sistema operativo trae un cliente muy básico para poder conectarse.
Tan solo abre la terminal (Ctrl+Shift+C) y digita

```
 ssh <nombreusuario>@<ip-remoto>
```

Si te tira un aviso sobre fingerprint, le pones yes y ya colocas tu contraseña y estás dentro. En tu servidor remoto te haces un git pull de tu repo en la carpeta que corresponda.

Comment: Gracias, me aclaraste muy bien. Si, es cierto que el sistema operativo trae OpenSsh Client.